# How to create a symlink for php project folder in apache's /var/www/html

Tags: php, apache, localhost, chmod

I want to symlink my php project folder "php-project" in `/var/www/html`. So whenever i run apache.ie. `http://localhost/php-project`. The website runs locally. 
I tried using the following commands

```
ln -s /Downloads/php-website /var/www/html/php-project
```

It shows up when i cd to `/var/www/html` . But whenever i visit the link `"localhost/php-website"` . It shows

> 403 Forbidden

Even when i try to give permissions to the `/var/www/html/php-project`

chmod -777 php-project

It shows

> error ": cannot operate on dangling symlink 'php-website'.

Please help me to solve this problem , such that the project folder can be used with the apache server for development process locally.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, Apache does not follow symbolic links, for obvious reasons.
This can be changed in the apache config, or for one site specifically by adding this to the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Also, please make sure you do not use chmod 777 on a system that is accessible from the web (or ever, preferably). For a complete write-up of what to do, see an answer on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: Thanks will remember that ! :)